# Find $f(x)=\sum_{0}^\infty u_k(x)$ and show it converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-continuity

I'm working on series and sequences of functions by my own. Specifically, pointwise and unofrm convergence, and some examples using Taylor series. One of the exercises stated the next question:

"For every integer $k$, let $u_k=\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x\in$ [k,k+1)} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

Find $f(x)=\sum_{0}^\infty u_k(x)$, and show directly from the definition that the series converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$ for all $R>0$, but does not on $(-\infty,\infty)$".

Normally, I was expecting to find $f(x)=Lim  f_n(x_0)$ as $n \to \infty$ on the corresponding $I=[-R,R]$ and finally to show that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$

However, for finding the correspondent function I had problems and second, how to prove it. I dunno how is gonna be the functional form. As uniform convergence needs to be proved, I guess the resulting $n$ will not depend on $x$ and only on $\varepsilon$. Any advice will be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean about $\sum_0^\infty u_k(x)$ What is the index that you are using? is it $k$?

Comment: Exactly, the index is $k$

Comment: Then you have a problem. $$f(x)=\left\{\begin {array}{ccc} 2& \mathrm{if}& x\in \mathbb Z \\
1 &\mathrm{O.W.}\end{array}\right.$$
This doesn't converge uniformly for all $x\in \mathbb R$, as well as for $x\in [-R,R]$ unless $R=0$.

Comment: @Sentinel135 The function $f$ is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 2 &\mbox{ if } x\in \mathbb{Z}\cap (0,\infty) \\ 1 &\mbox{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ Also, if $K$ is a positive integer greater than $R$, then $f_n(x) :=\sum_0^n u_k(x) = f(x)$ for all $n\geq K$ and $x\in [-R,R]$. Thus, $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$ on $[-R,R]$.

Answer (score 0):

If we're are summing for $k\ge 0$ then @i707107 is slightly off as well. the function $f$ is $$f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 0&\mathrm {if}& x<0\\ 2&\mathrm {if}& x\in \mathbb Z\cap(0,\infty)\\ 1 &&\mathrm {O.W.}\end{array} \right.$$ 
Other than that @i707107 is right. Let $N:= \lceil R\rceil$ then for $n\ge N$, we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. I was mixing up uniformly continuous with uniformly convergent.

While $N$ is independent of $x$, $N$ isn't independent of $R$. This is why $f_n(x) \rightarrow f$ isn't uniform for $(-\infty,\infty)$.  Another way to put this is that there doesn't exist an $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $N>\infty$. Therefore we can't find an $N$ large enough such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for every $x\in (-\infty,\infty)$. FYI this is more of the concept rather than a strict proof. That I leave to the OP.

Comment: Hint: the key is that for any $N$ you fix $\exists x\in \mathbb R$ such that $x>N+1$. And what happens at $f_n(x)$ for $x>N+1$?

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

What confuses me is also that uniform converge implies ordinary convergence and I was thinking that this function doesn't converge, but I forgot that it was asked around $[-R,R]$